# LDAP protocol vs other Directory Service Protocol

Tags: ldap, protocols, distributed, naming, directoryservices

What are the reason one would use any other protocol for Naming/Directory Services other than LDAP when LDAP is being a common standard?

Comment: What's the reason for the question? Is somebody actually doing this? Planning to do it?

Comment: reason for question: To understand LDAP and directory services and the difference between them.

Comment: You seem to be assuming the consequent, i.e. that there *is* a difference, and specifically that there is another directory protocol. If you have one in mind, name it. All the directory services I'm aware of use LDAP.

Answer (score -1):

There is only 1 alternative to LDAP as far as I learnt (after searching and reading few articles) and that is X.500. Below is the conclusion from [one of the comparisions](http://nlc-bnc.ca/iso/ill/document/ill_directory/X_500andLDAP.pdf)

> A popular implementation is to use X.500 as the backbone for the 
>   directory and use LDAP as the front-end interface. This allows a
>   better  performing Client with a more integrated Server network

Disclaimer: This is based on just 20 mins of research.

Resources (http://nlc-bnc.ca/iso/ill/document/ill_directory/X_500andLDAP.pdf and http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/ic-6033.html)

Comment: I think LDAP is an implementation of Directory Service using X.500 protocol. Thus it might not be right saying that X.500 is different protocol.

Comment: Correct. X.500 is the directory schema basically, not a protocol at all.